# When I create a new object how cna I make it align with my previous

Tags: modeling

I'm watching a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYKQwMc-WdE
and at 4:39 he creates a new object and it's instantly aligned with the barrel!

Comment: When you add a cylinder, then add another one, they point the same way along the world axes by default. New objects are added at 3D cursor, so if the 3D cursor is in the same place, and the first cylinder wasn't moved, both cylinders will be in the same location. Did you perhaps change the 3D cursor location between adding objects?

Comment: As Acro says, the new object will appear where you put your 3D cursor, if you want your 3D cursor to be at the same place as the first object, select this object and press shift S > Cursor To Selected, then create your new object